# Change the toolbar color

Tags: ios, swift

It is working for navigationBar:

```
var colour = UIColor.red
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = colour
```

But do not work for toolbar:

```
self.navigationController?.toolbar.tintColor = colour
```

I searched the internet and stack overflow. No answer is workable for me.
Some people said:

```
self.toolbar.barTintColor = UIColor.redColor()
```

It is also not working for me. (value of type 'thisView' has no member 'toolbar')

I want to edit the toolbar color in coding. No change in the storyboard setting. Thanks.

EDIT:
I am working on adding a toolbar under the webview. Like go back, stop, reload.

[image]

```
    //

    import UIKit

    class ViewController: UIViewController {


    @IBOutlet weak var webView: UIWebView!

    var colour = UIColor.red

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = colour

        // problem in here ..........................
        self.navigationController?.toolbar.tintColor = UIColor.black


        let URL = NSURL(string: "https://www.apple.com")        
        webView.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(url: URL! as URL) as URLRequest)
    }



    @IBAction func backButton(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        webView.goBack()
    }


    @IBAction func nextButton(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        webView.goForward()
    }

    @IBAction func refreshButton(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        webView.reload()
    }

    @IBAction func stopbutton(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        webView.stopLoading()
    }

}
```

Comment: barTintColor should work as long as you're accessing the toolbar property on the navigation controller not just self.toolbar. See my below answer

Comment: toolBar.barTintColor = UIColor.red 
This code is working for my in swift 3, Xcode 8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've just got a toolbar that is on a ViewController in Your Storyboard all you need to do is add an IBOutlet to your View Controller and connect the toolbar in the storyboard to that outlet. This code goes in your ViewController

```
@IBOutlet var toolbar: UIToolbar?
```

Then, in the storyboard, hold the control button and click drag from View Controller (in the left sidebar) to your toolbar. This will create a connection between the toolbar in the storyboard to the toolbar var in your code. After that connection is made all you need to do is set the barTintColor on that toolbar variable like so:

```
self.toolbar.barTintColor = UIColor.blue
```

Comment: I dont set the toolbar to be hidden. It is still not working using .barTintColor

Comment: Its hidden by default, you have to set it to not be hidden.

Comment: If thats not it, can you show some more code? I need a bit more context to figure out exactly whats going on wrong

Comment: when I added the first line of code, the toolbar disappeared somehow.

Comment: I am working on adding a toolbar under the webview. Like go back, stop, reload.

Comment: Edit your original question with some more code, maybe the entire function where you are setting this stuff up and I might be able to help a bit more

Comment: Are you using a navigation controller in the storyboard? Or is it just a navigationBar and a toolbar placed onto a View Controller?

Comment: Also it looks like since you have the toolbar on the storyboard you don't need my first line of code, so I'm removing it

Comment: A toolbar placed onto a View Controller. Sorry that I am quite new for swift3.

Comment: Ah ha! Thats where the disconnect is. I updated my answer with how to change the color of a toolbar that is created in interface builder, but you want to change the color in code.

Comment: Okay, I got it. Thanks for helping the ios beginner and finding out where the problem is.

Comment: No problem man, we've all been there! Good luck with your project

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this function a few days ago to kinda workaround the fact that you can't change the color.

```
func setStatusBarColor(){
        let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width, height: 20.0))
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 81/255, green: 184/255, blue: 222/255, alpha: 1)
        self.view.addSubview(view)
    }
```

Also make sure to set the statusbar to .lightContent

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarStyle = .LightContent
```